# af:inputListOfValues does not open for selection in Oracle ADF

Tags: java, oracle-adf

Hi I am trying to Implement LOV on ADF jspx page based on View Object to show different currencies but it won't work. I have tried the below code for currency field.

```
<af:inputListOfValues value="#{bindings.Currency.inputValue}"
                              label="Currency"
                              popupTitle="Search and Select: #{bindings.Currency.hints.label}"
                              autoSubmit="true"
                              required="true"
                              columns="#{bindings.Currency.hints.displayWidth}"
                              shortDesc="#{bindings.Currency.hints.tooltip}"
                              id="it115" readOnly="false" 
                              model="#{bindings.Currency.listOfValuesModel}">
                  <f:validator binding="#{bindings.Currency.validator}"/>
                  <af:autoSuggestBehavior/>
</af:inputListOfValues>
```

Comment: Thanks Issue resolved by adding the Binding again on adf page.

Answer (score 0):

can you please also share corresponding bindings in page def file.

Some times , the improper bindings may cause the issue.
Please try to re-add the Lov .

Comment: thanks, I already resolved this issue, It was actually binding issue.